# XML Serialization Issue - Object Will Serialize But Not Deserialize Some Properties

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a rather complex business object that I seem to be having trouble with. The object will serialize with no issues, I can go to the XML file it's serialized to, and see that the values are indeed stored in the file. However, when I try to deserialize the object, the properties in question do not come in with their saved values, they are strings, so they are coming in as String.Empty values. The object has many properties, most of which are working without a hitch, but I have this one set of String properties that just seem to be stuck. Example

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
   public String NameWorking { get; set; }
   public String TitleNotWorking { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

When I serialize to "obj.xml" and open said file with Notepad, I can see the node NameValue, and node TitleValue, which is correct for the serialization, but when i trace the debug, when the "obj.xml" file is deserialized, the resulting Foo object has the correct value for NameWorking, but just String.Empty for TitleNotWorking. Is there a bug of some sort that could be causing this? Is there a workaround?
Additionally, I don't know if this is part of the issue, but the properties in question are databound properties in the application. But all the other working properties are as well.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the [XML Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx)

In your case it would be the following

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
   [XmlElement]
   public String NameWorking { get; set; }

   [XmlElement]
   public String TitleNotWorking { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Strange, as I have other String properties that are working, without the XMLAttribute tag, but I'll try that and see if it has any effect. Thanks!

Comment: @Wanabrutbeer It might be `XmlElement` as well, I'm not entirely sure which

Comment: Add element name [XmlElement("TitleNotWorking")].  Make sure the name is spelled correctly and the lower and uppercase letter are correct.  The object name in the classes doesn't have to match the tags in the XML file.  The names in the XmlElement are used to cross reference the tag with the class name.